# What is the best way to setup faxing in a local network?

Tags: fax

Is there a way to setup simple faxing, as simple as emailing a document?. Also to multiple contacts at once and to predefined mailing lists.

Please let me know a good client / server.

Free / Opensource, preferred.

Thanks

Comment: What OS on the server and clients?

Comment: Clients are mostly windows XP, server can be configured to any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) open-source telephony server could do it, with some plugins.
Or [Hylafax](http://www.hylafax.org/), which appears to be quite popular too.

I've no experience with either solution, but both are open-source, free and well-known. You'll still need a modem to actually send and receive the faxes.

Other options are web services that provide fax2email and email2fax. Hundreds of those around, but none-free for obvious reasons.

Comment: Does it work with a simple modem.

Comment: +1 for HylaFAX, which is trivial to set up and works with any standard modem. Asterisk however would be just about the ultimate in overkill.

Comment: after trying to install hylafax, which is not much of a trouble. But getting modem to work on linux is a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 2):

For a Fax Server you could use HylaFax, with a web interface like [AvantFax](http://www.avantfax.com/), you could also use un the client side [JHylaFAX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhylafax/) 
that is an open source and platform independent client for HylaFAX.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your volume and users you may find it easier to just outsource it to a service such as myfax,efax, etc.  They can do number porting in some situations and offer a lot of features that you may find helpful.